# Selecting a record on the basis of last modified status

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table

```
fieldid  STATUS  CreatedWhen

122      Down    2012-05-16 14:26:56.263
122      Down    2012-05-16 14:26:56.250
122      Down    2012-05-16 14:26:56.233
122      Down    2012-05-16 14:26:56.217
122      Up      2012-05-16 14:26:56.200
54       Up      2011-10-07 10:19:33.873
```

I want to select only those fields whose latest status is Up, the result should be only the last row, because fieldid:122 has the latest status as 'Down'. Something like getting the max date only if status is up.

edit: sql server 2008

Comment: Which database are you using?  (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, ...)

Comment: Please remember to give your table a name; it helps everyone give consistent answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure which DBMS you are using as you did not indicate, but here is a DBMS-agnostic solution which should work regardless of the DBMS you are using:

```
SELECT
    a.fieldid
FROM
    (
        SELECT fieldid, MAX(CreatedWhen) AS maxdate
        FROM tbl
        GROUP BY fieldid
    ) a
INNER JOIN
    tbl b ON 
        a.fieldid = b.fieldid AND
        b.CreatedWhen = a.maxdate AND
        b.STATUS = 'Up'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to see all of the requirements. Perhaps this is what you mean?

```
SELECT fieldid, max(CreatedWhen)
FROM <youtable>
WHERE field_id not in (
  -- exclude any field that has at least one 'Down'
  SELECT DISTINCT fieldid
  FROM <yourtable>
  WHERE STATUS='Down'
)
GROUP BY fieldid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTbl
WHERE Status = 'Up'
ORDER BY CreatedWhen DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL server try

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM <TABLE>
WHERE 
    STATUS = 'Up'
ORDER BY
    CreatedWhen DESC
```

In details:
TOP 1: select only the first row of the resultset
The where clause select only the row with the Status = 'Up'
The order by define the order of the resultset. In this case DESC stand for the older row before the newer. So the first will be the last created

Comment: but i want all the rows which have the latest status 'Up', this would only select one row